# Why isn't my CSS3 loading animation working on mobile?

Tags: css, animation, mobile

it works fine on desktop but on mobile im getting the static state instead of the fading in and out.

I put the code here...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvKZGW

```
@keyframes flickerAnimation {
0%   { opacity:1; }
50%  { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
0%   { opacity:1; }
50%  { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
0%   { opacity:1; }
50%  { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
0%   { opacity:1; }
50%  { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:1; }
}

.loading  {
-webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
-moz-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
-o-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
background: #215c87;
display: block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What 'mobile' doesn't work?

Comment: any mobile device it seems. safari or chrome